# Comparison fails when comparing object properties with each other

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm encountering an odd issue which should actually be a done deal.
My code is not going inside the final loop, even though the data is correct.

```
<?php
$database->setQuery('SELECT cat_title, cat_id, parent_id FROM #__jdownloads_cats WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY parent_id');      
$cats = $database->loadObjectList();

foreach (array_filter($cats, function($x) { return $x->parent_id == 0; }) as $a) {
    foreach (array_filter($cats, function($x) { return $x->parent_id == $a->cat_id; }) as $b) {             
        // ..
    }           
}
?>
```

See:

```
print_r($a); 
stdClass Object
(
    [cat_title] => Category example
    [cat_id] => 1
    [parent_id] => 0
)
```

and

```
print_r($cats);
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cat_title] => Category example
            [cat_id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cat_title] => Subcategory example
            [cat_id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

)
```

My comparison is failing: `$x->parent_id == $a->cat_id`.
Works as expected if I change to `$x->parent_id == 0` or `$x->parent_id == 1`.

A gettype says those values are strings. What am I missing? TIA.

*edit*:
I don't get it:

```
echo $a->cat_id == 1 ? "it's 1\n" : "its not 1\n";
```

it's 1

```
print_r(array_filter($cats, function($x) { return $x->parent_id == 1; }));
```

Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cat_title] => Subcategory example
            [cat_id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

)

```
print_r(array_filter($cats, function($x) { return $x->parent_id == $a->cat_id; }));
```

Array
(
)

Comment: Just on a side note, I would recommend using up to date coding standards for your query: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: the sql string query is actually here only as an example :), but yeah ty for the tip!

Comment: what do you get if you just do `print_r($a)` and `print_r(array_filter($cats, function($x) { return $x->parent_id == $a->cat_id; }))` right after the first `foreach`? If the last one results in an empty array, you will obviously never get into the second `foreach`.

Comment: well yeah it is an empty array. that's what my question is asking, why isn't the comparison evaluating?

Comment: i didn't put a `use`. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something I didn't know about PHP:

You have to explicitly declare variables inherited from the parent scope, with the use keyword.

So `function($x)` becomes= `function($x) use($a)` otherwise everything else is out of scope!.